# JavaScript, RegExp - replace with evaluated expression involving tagged expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, evaluate

RegExp can replace matched patterns with replacements involving what is known as *Tagged Expressions*

Example:

```
var s = "... some string with full things...";
s = s.replace(/(some|full)/gi, "\"aw$1\");
```

which will result in

```
'... "awsome" string with "awfull" things...'
```

And life are cool, because **some** and **full** are matched, and $1 in the replaced string reflects the matched *Tagged Expression* in the braces, in this case - exactly only **some** or **full**.

Now, that we got the idea - 
I'm looking for an idea to do the following:

String before:

```
"{timeOfEffect: 3*24*60*60 }"
```

String after

```
"{timeOfEffect: 259200}"
```

The values are represented like that because they are edited by humans to graspable terms like (60 sec * 60 min * 24 hours)*3 => 3 days (don't ask. Client's request), but read in computer terms like 259200 in seconds, and could contain many occuring of that pattern.

I was thinking to try to create a replacement expression that multiplies $1 and $2, or even pass $1 and $2 to a function, or pass $1 * $2 to an evaluation context, but I have to create a function for it and do it manually.

The closest I got is

```
var x = /([0-9]*)\s\*\s([0-9]*)/g
  , r = function(m){
           return m[1] * m[2];
        }
while (m = x.exec(s))
  s = s.replace( x, r(m));
```

That sucks a little because `exec` returns **only the first match**.
After handling it in the replace statement - next search starts again from the start of the string - which is a string of 60K length...

A good solution will be one of the following:
a) perform the match starting from an index (without creating a new substring for that)
b) provide a replace expression that allows evaluation

The alternative approach will be to tokenize the string, and process it in bits - which is a total alternative to the `RegExp` that will take a lot of code and effort, in which case I'll just live with the performance penalty or give a better fight on a better alternative for this requirement...

Help anybody?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var s = "timeOfEffect: 3*24*60*60 var: 6*8 ";
var r = new RegExp("([0-9*+-/]{0,}[0-9])","g");
s = s.replace(r,function(match){ return eval(match); });
alert(s)
```

Comment: wow. this one is cool! with a little adjustment to the reg-exp - it covers all basic arithmethics (assuming they are syntactically correct)! – Radagast the Brown 0 secs ago edit

Comment: Ok, here's the final solution.
It can easily extended to support braces too, but I don't need any.

The problem with the original offer was that it matched simple numbers too - which don't need replacement.
`var r =  new RegExp("([0-9\\.]+)([\\*+-\\/].)([0-9\\*+-\\/]+)([0-9])","g");`
`r = function(m,m1,m2,m3,m4){  `
`try{`
`return ":" + eval(m1+m2+m3+m4)`
`}catch(ex){ `
`return ":\"@@EVAL_ERROR:" + m1+m2+m3+m4 + "\""`
`}`
`}`
`}`
`s = s.replace(x,r)`

The output obviously is checked against "@@EVAL_ERROR" and sends mails about broken configurations...

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey kewwwwwlll! the pre-last argument to the match function is the match-index in the searched string, and the last argument is the entire searched string itself!! and it's damn fast!
I can use it to emit accurate parse errors to the editors!! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = '{timeOfEffect: 3*24*60*60}, {timeOfEffect: 1+7}, {timeOfEffect: 20-3}, {timeOfEffect: 3 / 0}';

var result = str.replace(/\s([\d\/\*\-\+\s]+?)\}/g, function(all, match) {
    return eval(match) + '}';
});

document.body.innerHTML = result;
// {timeOfEffect:259200}, {timeOfEffect:8}, {timeOfEffect:17}, {timeOfEffect:Infinity}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gd46/).

`eval()` is safe to use because we have ensured the string only contains `0-9`, , `\n`, `\t`, `/`, `*`, `-` and `+`. [I *was* hoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) there may be something like `Math.parse()`, but there isn't.

If you need more complex math that requires parenthesis, simply add escaped `(` and `)` to the regex character range.